# Bake shader output into an image texture

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I am really new to blender and I am trying to get some basics so forgive me if my question is not clear, uses the wrong terminology, or does not make sense.

I understood what is baking by watching some tutorials but maybe not at 100%. I followed a tutorial through which I was able to create a nice looking floor with different nodes. The nodes all converge into a *Material Output* node. I was wondering: is it possible to bake all these nodes into an image texture? I was trying to do it but without success.

Below you can see a screenshot of my current project also with the options I used to try to bake the nodes into the `floor_bake` image texture. I think that what is definitely not correct is the "Bake Type" which I set to "Diffuse".

[image]

Could you please help me?